# Manjaro+Remmina+RDP (Win10) lags 3-5 seconds when opening a new window (e.g open thunderbird, windows explorer, etc)

Tags: windows-10, rdp, manjaro

I use Remmina to connect to a Win10 machine via RDP. It runs perfectly smooth as long as I am not opening new windows or switch between them. However, when I open Thunderbird for instance, it freezes for 2-5 seconds till it runs smooth again. It seems it does this for all more complex windows I open up (or switch to), which is pretty annoying.

I already tried downgrading the quality settings within reminna and the resolution, but it does not help. The connection is also not the problem.

Comment: Do you have enough ram? Thunderbird and many other apps based on electron use lots of rams that can affect the performance of other apps' running.

Comment: @maanijou It is not ram related, since I also assumed that and then I checked, still enough free ram.
I was fiddling around with the settings some more and now the problem is gone. I'm not sure what setting ultimately fixed it and I also cannot reproduce the lag. I think enabling "dynamic resolution" fixed it, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Further fiddling with remmina settings and it seems, that it fixed itself. However, I'm unsure which setting is responsible for resolving the problem. Last thing I remember to change, was enabling **dynamic resolution**, after enabling this setting, everything seems to work nicely (works nicely also after disabling it again).